# pass value of cell from table row to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to pass the value of the `data-count` cell to a variable using either jQuery or Javascript. How can I do it? Here is the HTML:

***edit*** I should have stated that the value of `id-offer=186000` is not constant and differs from page to page

```
<table class="vis" id="own_offers_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="offer_container " id="offer_186000" data-id="186000" data-count="30" data-village="" data-wanted_wood="900" data-wanted_stone="0" data-wanted_iron="0">
```

Thanks again for any help

Comment: Under what event are you trying to pass the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the `tr` using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or by the class using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
2. Get the `data-` attribute value using [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes#JavaScript_Access)

```js
//var count = document.getElementById('offer_186000').dataset.count;
var count = document.querySelector('.offer_container').dataset.count;
alert(count);
```

```html
<table class="vis" id="own_offers_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="offer_container" id="offer_186000" data-id="186000" data-count="30" data-village="" data-wanted_wood="900" data-wanted_stone="0" data-wanted_iron="0">
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou. This worked perfectly - however, I should have stated that the id of "offer_186000" changes from page to page. How can I pass this data when this id is different?

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

```
var count = $('#offer_186000').data('count');
```

Setting the value:

```
$('#offer_186000').data('count', value);
```

If you can't use it's id

```
$('#own_offers_table').find('.offer_container').data('count');
```

For Setting the value:

```
$('#own_offers_table').find('.offer_container').data('count', value);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Setting Value(Jquery Command):

```
$("#offer_186000").attr('data-count').val('30');
```

For getting value(Jquery Command):

```
var value = $("#offer_186000").attr('data-count').val();
alert(value);
```